# Create loading screen when search form button is clicked in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, loading

I need to submit a search form and while searching is done in controller the page loading screen should appear an one the operation is finished is controller the view should be loaded . How to acieve this

Here is my home view

```
 <form action="Test/search">
       <input type="text" name="value1" >
       <input type="text" name="value2" >
       <input type="text" name="value3" >
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" >
    </form>
```

Here is my controller

```
function Search(){
    //posting values 
     // search operation 
    $this->load->view('Search_result_view', $searchdata);

    }
```

My Search_result_view displays the results, I need to load a loading screen after submit button is clicked and before the view is loaded completely

Comment: kindly put the code where you try adding the loading functionality. To get you started you may try this one http://vadimsva.github.io/waitMe/

Answer (score 0):

Submit your form using **jquery** like below

```
$('#submit_button').on('click',function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     //Add a code to show your loader.
     $('form').submit();
});
```

**Into your search view by default give class which shows the loader along with page load and add the below jquery which will hide your loader after page loads**

```
$(window).load(function(){
   // PAGE IS FULLY LOADED  
   //hide your loader
});
```

As it will refresh the page so it might possible that you can see a gap between loader appear while loading a search result. for better you can load a view with a **AJAX** when you can show a loader in **beforeSend function** and hide a loader after you get a response.

Answer (score 0):

Below code is dummy code using this code you can perform search operation using ajax.

VIEW FILE: `submit_view.php`

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Submit CodeIgniter Form Using jQuery</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Marcellus' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(). "css/submit.css" ?>">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(). "js/submit.js" ?>"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<?php echo form_open('submit_ctrl',array('id'=>'form')); ?>
<h1>Submit CodeIgniter Form Using jQuery</h1>
<?php echo form_label('Name :'); ?> <?php echo form_error('dname'); ?>
<?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'dname', 'name' => 'dname')); ?>
<?php echo form_label('Email :'); ?> <?php echo form_error('demail'); ?>
<?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'demail', 'name' => 'demail')); ?>
<?php echo form_label('Mobile No. :'); ?> <?php echo form_error('dmobile'); ?>
<?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'dmobile', 'name' => 'dmobile')); ?>
<?php echo form_label('Address :'); ?> <?php echo form_error('daddress'); ?>
<?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'daddress', 'name' => 'daddress')); ?>
<?php echo ('<p id="submit">Submit</p>'); ?>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller: `submit_ctrl.php`

```
<?php
class submit_ctrl extends CI_Controller {
function __construct() {
parent::__construct();
$this->load->model('submit_model');
}
function index(){
$this->load->library('form_validation'); // Including Validation Library.
$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>'); // Displaying Errors in Div
$this->form_validation->set_rules('dname', 'Username', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[15]'); // Validation for Name Field
$this->form_validation->set_rules('demail', 'Email', 'required|valid_email'); // Validation for E-mail field.
$this->form_validation->set_rules('dmobile', 'Contact No.', 'required|regex_match[/^[0-9]{10}$/]'); // Validation for Contact Field.
$this->form_validation->set_rules('daddress', 'Address', 'required|min_length[10]|max_length[50]'); // Validation for Address Field.
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
$this->load->view('submit_view');
}else {
// Initializing database table columns.
$data = array(
'Student_Name' => $this->input->post('dname'),
'Student_Email' => $this->input->post('demail'),
'Student_Mobile' => $this->input->post('dmobile'),
'Student_Address' => $this->input->post('daddress')
);
$this->submit_model->form_insert($data); // Calling Insert Model and its function.
echo "<script>alert('Form Submitted Successfully....!!!! ');</script>";
$this->load->view('submit_view'); // Reloading after submit.
}
}
}
?>
```

Model: `submit_model.php`

```
<?php
class submit_model extends CI_Model{
function __construct() {
parent::__construct();
}
function form_insert($data){
$this->db->insert('employee', $data);
}
}
?>
```

jQuery script: `submit.js`

On click of submit button, the following jQuery code executes.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submit").click(function(){
$("#form").submit();  // jQuery's submit function applied on form.
});
});
```